# MySQL Database Error: Too many columns

Tags: mysql

I am running the following query to pivot data from a table:

```
SELECT 
time_stamp,
SUM(CASE WHEN sensor_id=000001 THEN temp ELSE 0 END) AS 'temp_000001',
SUM(CASE WHEN sensor_id=000002 THEN temp ELSE 0 END) AS 'temp_000002',
```

...

```
SUM(CASE WHEN sensor_id=003372 THEN temp ELSE 0 END) AS 'temp_003372'

FROM sensor_data
GROUP BY time_stamp
```

The query should return a result set with 3372 columns and 8928 rows (number of different time_stamps). I am getting a "Too many columns" error which is strange because the query has worked before. sensor_data contains measurements of 3372 sensors at 8928 time points. If I run the same query on a table which contains measurements of 3372 sensors at 288 time points it works. So the number of columns can't really be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum number of columns in MySQL is deceptive.

It can be 4096 (which is the documented MAX_FIELDS in the source), but it can also be much lower, depending on the *names* of the columns!

The gory details are here: [Understanding the Maximum Number of Columns in a MySQL Table](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/04/08/understanding-the-maximum-number-of-columns-in-a-mysql-table/)

You might also have had your query work before because it wasn't creating a temp table. Maybe the timestamp column was indexed before and it isn't anymore?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are running into the problem of the row length of the temporary table needed to compute GROUP BY. The number of columns has a hard limit of 4096 which you do not appear to be reaching, but the row length is limited to 64K (without blobs). There are a number of things you can try to get around the problem:

- replace `temp` with `cast(temp as signed)` or use some other casting trick to force the expression to be of the type that requires the least possible amount of storage
- split the query into a `union` of two `group by` queries
- create a temporary resulting table manually with `time_stamp` column and all the resulting columns being of the smallest possible storage type and populate it manually using `insert into ... select ... on duplicate key update ...` - then read your result from that table - essentially performing a poor-man `group by` with your own hands.
- change the type of temp to the smallest possible that your data will permit. You can get a recommendation from MySQL by doing `select temp from sensor_data procedure analyse()`

Comment: still doesn't work for me and even if it did, this is starting to feel like I am using the wrong tool for the job. but how else would one pivot large data sets like that?

Comment: Can you post the details? What is the type of temp?

Comment: temp is VARCHAR(50). Given that I am not hitting the actual hard limit of 4096 columns is there any way to increase the row length limit of 64k? I am a bit confused as to why I keep running into these seemingly arbitrary limitations. At no point in time do I see memory usage of my machine reaching it's limits, so why would MySQL not allow to use it. I get that there is a column limit for tables, to ensure reasonable database design, but for queries?

Comment: MySQL needs to create a temp table to deal with the GROUP BY and the stars align that it overflows the 64k limit. Try playing with the type of temp to make it the smallest possible. If that does not help, create http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve example, I'll be happy to debug.